# Outlook 2007 adding a gap around table in html email

Tags: html, email, html-email

http://www.uvisandals.ca/Sandals_Media_Luncheon.html

when copy and pasted into outlook 2007, there is a gap around the inner table, and a 1 px spacing around the images.

I'm losing my mind.

I've tried everything I can think of

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need `style="display:block;"` on the images

Comment: if that doesn't work, use this for your tables: `<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="640" style="border-collapse:collapse; padding:0; margin:0px;">`